# How to ignore the available_on attribute of Spree::Product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

`Spree::Product.available_on` is not a required field but the product won't be shown unless you set a date in the past to it.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Let's say all products are always available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always [override spree](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/logic.html), in your case you need to change [this line](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/search/base.rb#L37) from:

```
base_scope = Spree::Product.spree_base_scopes.active
```

to

```
base_scope = Spree::Product.spree_base_scopes
```

The `active` method is defined [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product/scopes.rb#L204), you can see how it is checking for the `available_on` date.

With that being said, I think it will be easier if you set an `available_on` date for all of your products:

```
Spree::Product.update(available_on: 1.day.ago)
```